# ag-grid: access row data in filter test function

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-vue

While using custom filter options in a grid column I encountered the need to compare the `cellValue` with some other value of the same row and can't seem to find how to do so, given that no reference to the row data is passed to the `test` function.

```
columnDefs: [
{
    field: "Column 1",
    (...)
    filterParams: {
        filterOptions: [
            'lessThan',
            'greaterThan',
            {
                displayKey: 'lessThanColumn2',
                displayName: 'Less Than column 2',
                test: function(filterValue, cellValue) {
                    return cellValue < rowData.column2; // <------ how?
                }
            },
    }
}
(...)
]
```

Using a valueGetter to include all needed data in the cell value and displaying only the relevant part using a Cell Renderer seems to be a workaround.

Is it possible to achieve this in any other way without a custom filter?

Comment: I think custom filter suits better for row level filtering. What you can do is define a custom filter satisfies your needs and trigger it from the column test fubction

Answer (score 0):

ColDef also has possibility to define filterValueGetter, you can try to do something like this:

```
filterValueGetter: (params: ValueGetterParams) => {
    const rowData = params.data.$sourceDataItem;
    return rowData; // pass all row data
},
```

I guess the filterValue in your test function will now contain row data.